# Get taxonomy of custom post type based on post ID

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, shortcode

I am trying to add a column in admin table listing of my custom post type `cota` that is the current taxonomy `tipo` but it's not printing it.

Here's the current code:

```
function la_set_cota_columns($columns){

   $newColumns = array();
   $newColumns['title'] = 'Título da Cota';
   $newColumns['comissao'] = 'Comissão';
   $newColumns['proprietario'] = 'Proprietário';
   $newColumns['vencimento'] = 'Vencimento';
   $newColumns['tipo'] = 'Tipo de Cota';

   return $newColumns;
}
add_filter('manage_cota_posts_columns', 'la_set_cota_columns');


function la_cota_custom_column($column, $post_id){
   $content = get_post_meta($post_id);

   switch( $column ){

       case 'comissao' :
         echo $content['comissao'][0];
       break;

       case 'proprietario' :
         echo $content['proprietario'][0];
       break;

       case 'vencimento' :
         echo $content['vencimento'][0];
       break;

       case 'tipo':
         echo get_metadata('cota', $post_id, 'tipo', $single = true);
       break;
   }

}
add_action('manage_cota_posts_custom_column', 'la_cota_custom_column', 10, 2);
```

Actual results can be found [here](https://imgur.com/a/Cp53G)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are looking to print the terms associated with the current post listed in the table... As such, you instead need to use the [wp_get_post_terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) function:

```
$term_names = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'tipo', array('fields' => 'names')); // returns an array of term names
echo implode(', ', $term_names);
```

Ans just one little comment about the function call you did use: the last parameter is optional, which means you can either pass a *value* or nothing at all. If you omit it, it will have the default value *false*. But you don't pass the default value when you make the function call:

```
get_metadata('cota', $post_id, 'tipo', true);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks very much! It worked! About the get_metadata last parameter, i thought the default parameter was false! But thanks a lot.

Comment: Awesome - but you are actually about the default value. I took your code as a copy-paste of the function call in the codex. I've adapted my answer: it is indeed false by default - sorry about that.

Comment: Hmm, nice! Yes, WP Codex is helping me a lot, since i'm no Wordpress expert hehe. But thanks a lot!